# How do I fetch keywords from the server in which bot is not there see my code and then Tell

Tags: discord.py

This bot fetches keywords from the channel id but only if the bot is there in the server of which the channel id is given not if I give channel id of a server in which bot is not there but I want to fetch keyword from another server now how to do that

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    x = client.get_channel(61993237976252417)
    b = client.get_channel(623205069084688394)
    c = client.get_channel(623888107124555776)

    if message.content == 'yy' or message.content == 'y' or message.content == 'yyy' and message.channel is x:

        await b.send('**y**')

        time.sleep(0.5)
    if message.content == '...' or message.content == '..' or message.content == '.' and message.channel is x:
        await b.send('**i**')
        time.sleep(0.5)

    if message.content == 'i' or message.content == 'ii' or message.content == 'iii' and message.channel is x:
        await b.send('**i**')
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: You bot cannot see messages in servers it is not a member of.

Comment: Can I use selfbot for it  what changes I have to make for it?

Comment: @user12128410 No, as self-bots are against Discord's ToS, and given your code, it would be pretty obvious considering the self-bot would send messages 24/7 only if there was a keyword.